# HST rebate when buying a vacant piece of land / lot and building one's own new home on it?

Tags: canada, hst, real-estate, ontario, rebate

I am looking at buying a vacant piece of land from a developer and building a house on it.

I realize I must pay HST on the purchase of the land.

If I act as the contractor/builder of my new home, are there any other HST rebates that I would qualify for in addition to the Ontario New Home rebate (Ontario tax portion)?

Do I need to do anything in particular to avail myself of other rebates?

Thanks for your help.